# Determine current Home screen widget / icon layout

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a Live Wallpaper feature (`android.software.live_wallpaper`) and within the `Engine` you obtain a `SurfaceHolder`, `Canvas` and so on:

Java:

```
SurfaceHolder holder = getSurfaceHolder();
Canvas canvas = holder.lockCanvas();
// Draw on the canvas
holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
```

C#:

```
Canvas canvas = SurfaceHolder.LockCanvas();
// Draw on the canvas
SurfaceHolder.UnlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
```

No problems creating the wallpaper `Service` and drawing on the `Canvas` but...

What I would like to do it to determine the current Home screen's layout or placement of widgets and icons in order to determine if I want to draw around them, resize my drawables to seen within the cluttered desktop or just to used the icons as a Pachinko machine and animate the balls falling down and bouncing off them, but I can not find an API to access that layout (assuming it is a collection of `View` and `ViewGroup`?).

Comment: @OP better show us the current screen(behavior) and expected screen you want to achieve.

Comment: "What I would like to do it to determine the current Home screen's layout or placement of widgets and icons" - This seems like it would vary from various installed launchers on phones. In your case it sounds like you might want to build your own launcher from the ground up.

Comment: @JonDouglas Thanks Jon, that would be an one way to go and if the budget allowed it ;-) , but out of scope for this project (a promotional OpenGL-based LiveWallPaper for a client's Android gaming business, these WallPapers are used on several hundred wall-mounted phones/tablets running sync'd demo scripts powered by Appium)... I was *hoping* to find a way to *read* the current widget/icon placement within the WallPaperService and determine where the dynamic content should be "rendered" for the best mosaic display...